# Compile dll using ATL with method parameter as Interfaces, but get them as coclasses

Tags: c++, .net, com, atl

I'm using a C++ ATL library. Methods in the IDL file are declared with a `IQTAction` parameter, but when I use this type library in .NET I get the methods parameters of type QTAction NOT IQTAction:

```
namespace COMTest3Lib
{
    [ClassInterface(0)]
    [Guid("C6DD8D8E-8375-4CA6-8534-007776D96215")]
    [TypeLibType(2)]
    public class QTTestClass : IQTTest, QTTest
    {
        public QTTestClass();
        public virtual void GetActiveAction(out QTAction pActionOut);
        public virtual void RunAction(QTAction pActionIn);
    }
}

namespace COMTest3Lib
{
    [CoClass(typeof(QTActionClass))]
    [Guid("FBCC87D9-4E5C-40D2-853F-E8548E625C5B")]
    public interface QTAction : IQTAction
    {
    }
}
```

Why is that? How do I get it to use the interface instead of the coclass as the parameter's type?

Here are my header and IDL files:

```
using namespace ATL;

//QTTest.h
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CQTTest :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CQTTest, &CLSID_QTTest>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IQTTest, &IID_IQTTest, &LIBID_COMTest3Lib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>
{
public:
    CQTTest()
    {
        m_pActiveAction.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_QTAction); //construct an action; 
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_QTTEST)


BEGIN_COM_MAP(CQTTest)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IQTTest)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
END_COM_MAP()

    DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

    HRESULT FinalConstruct()
    {
        return S_OK;
    }

    void FinalRelease()
    {
        ::MessageBox(NULL, L"#################QTTest is being disposed", L"info", 0);
    }

public:
    STDMETHOD(GetActiveAction)(/*out*/IQTAction** pActionOut);
    STDMETHOD(RunAction)(/*in*/IQTAction* pActionIn);

private:
    CComPtr<IQTAction> m_pActiveAction;
};

OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(QTTest), CQTTest)
```

IDL FILE:

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";
[
    object,
    uuid(FBCC87D9-4E5C-40D2-853F-E8548E625C5B),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IQTAction : IDispatch{
    [helpstring("method Run")] HRESULT Run(void);
};
[
    object,
    uuid(19F205D2-1D1C-4DB7-A731-498665CC297F),
    version(1.0)
]
interface IQTTest : IDispatch{
    [helpstring("method GetActiveAction")] HRESULT GetActiveAction([out] IQTAction** pActionOut);
    //[helpstring("method Run")] HRESULT Run(void);
    [helpstring("Run a specific action")] HRESULT RunAction([in] IQTAction* pActionIn);
};
[
    uuid(0E651E25-832E-4410-9A9E-F8CD8574F4D8),
]
library COMTest3Lib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(C6DD8D8E-8375-4CA6-8534-007776D96215)      
    ]
    coclass QTTest
    {
        [default] interface IQTTest;
    };
    [
        uuid(72D899CC-7722-4260-A441-3D1225132019)      
    ]
    coclass QTAction
    {
        [default] interface IQTAction;
    };
};
```

Comment: Why the down votes and the close votes?  If you don't understand the op, ask him for details.  To me, it's clear what is being asked: why is the `QTAction` .NET class type being used in the methods of `IQTTest` instead of the `IQTAction` .NET interface type?

Comment: `IQTAction` is only implemented by QTAction in the type library. .NET interop sees it and "merges" the definitions trying to simplify things. Nevertheless you see it as `QTAction` on .NET side, it is still `IQTAction` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the type library importer uses the coclass **interface** instead of the actual interface when it finds that there's only one coclass implementing that interface as the default within the same type library, and there's no way to prevent it from doing this.

However, note that `QTTest` and `IQTTest` are both **interfaces**, with the same Guid and methods.  But `QTTest` has an extra attribute, `CoClassAttribute(QTTestClass)`, that allows Microsoft's C# compiler to compile `new QTTest()` into `new QTTestClass()`.

This tlbimp.exe juggling makes VB6 programmers feel at home, but it's quite weird for C++ developers.  In your case, it only implies casting between two otherwise equivalent interface types.

Comment: I want to point out that, TLBIMP.exe also will not generate `QTTest` (coclass interface) when it's not in the same type library as the coclass implementing it, it will generate the raw interface (`IQTTest`).

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited the answer accordingly.